# How can I configure flow.js to use comments when my eslint adds spacing in my function arguments?

Tags: node.js, eslint, flowtype

My function is:

```
    getConferenceNumberAndPin: (description = null /*: string */ , entryPoints = null /*: Array<object> */ ) => {
```

As you can see, it adds a space before the comma: `*/ ,` as well as one before the `)`.

I am using `--fix` with eslint, so the spacing is automatically added. But now flowjs complains:

```
Unexpected token ,, expected the token )
```

How can I get the 2 to play nicely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue with the code is the placement of the type comments. [Function parameters with defaults](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/#toc-function-parameters-with-defaults) shows an example function declaration

```
function method(value: string = "default") { /* ... */ }
```

Notice that the type comes before the default value. Therefore, in your example, your function declaration would look like

```
function getConferenceNumberAndPin(
  description: ?string = null,
  entrypoints: ?Array<Object> = null
) { /* ... /* }
```

And, using the comment syntax (shortened the function name so it can be written on one line)

```
function f(description /*: ?string */ = null, entrypoints /*: ?Array<Object> */ = null): void {}
```

The spacing before and after the commas and parentheses should not matter. You can play around with your example at [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFAEwKYGcICcYAOsCiA9AFQBciA-FlPmAOaLmmIC8iYIANrwBpEGMAwCeBODFFYyVWgEFcuAIZiAPAHkARgCsM0AHyt2XHvwCU1AG5S0iAN4BfIA) to experiment with the spacing that eslint would insert.